# Is there any low level way to draw pixels to the screen?

Tags: c++, c

Most of the portable GUI and graphics libraries I know of seem to only call the different API functions for the OS they're running on, I was wondering if there was some form of portable (or non portable) way to talk directly to video memory to be able to draw pixels to the screen, or does the OS hide that functionality and you are only able to call its API functions?

Comment: Modern operating systems don't let you touch the video memory directly

Comment: You could use something like OpenGL (cross-platform, FOSS) or DirectX (Windows-only, closed source)

Comment: What if you're in a window and the user wants to move or resize it? Or you have the full screen, but the user wants to switch you out and regain control. Even if you had direct frame buffer access, you would have to very closely cooperate with the OS so as not to draw where and when you aren't supposed to.

Comment: Is there any ... screen? No such requirement is made by standard C or standard C++. With this in mind, you stand **no chance** of finding a portable answer. Of course there are non-portable answers, *zillions* of them, for all different OSes, but you'd need to specify which OSes you care about to get a good answer here. There's also no requirement that an OS exist, FWIW.

Comment: P.S. Both C and C++ are considered *high-level* programming languages by reputable programming books such as SICP.

Comment: No. The whole point of those libraries is that there is no portable way to talk to the graphics cards directly, so to have a portable way, you need a higher-level interface, and low-level backends that can talk to each specific kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last system I know which allowed direct video access to user program was the good old MS/DOS. I assume than its derivatives like FreeDOS still allow that. The problem is that in modern OS, a process can only access its own memory and must ask the OS for any other memory access. And as the video is shared by many processes (including system processes) only system API can directly control it.

You normally can find API that allows you to draw bitmaps on a *copy* of the video memory and then flush it, or that offer higher level accesses. Depending on the system you can even find APIs that map the actual video memory into your address space. But you must first ask kindly to  the kernel...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a play around, you can do this on a very inexpensive Raspberry Pi. I use a little Waveshare 3.5" RPi LCD with mine which is 320x480pixels and around $30

[image]

The screen shows up as `/dev/fb/0` (or maybe `1`) and if you `ssh` into the Raspberry Pi (rather than running X11 on the screen which you are about to mess up), you can splat whatever you like all over it.

For example, if you want to clear it, you just send a bunch of zeroes - I don't have it currently connected so I can't check easily, but it is like:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fb0
```

If you want to light the screen up white, send `1`s:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero | tr '\0' '\377' > /dev/fb1
```

If you want to draw any specific pixel with a colour, you just calculate the offset from the start and write a 16-bit, RGB565 pixel. You can do that in `C` or from the terminal with:

```
echo -e "\x15" | dd of=/dev/fb0 bs=2 skip=348
```

There is a brilliant, fun tutorial [here](http://raspberrycompote.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/low-level-graphics-on-raspberry-pi-part_9509.html).

---

Another option is to use VirtualBox and install a Linux distro that you can ssh into, then you can write all over the frame buffer using [this example](http://hacklab.cz/2012/04/22/usefulness-linux-framebuffer-virtual-console).

Answer (score 2):

One solution I know is directly manipulating the framebuffer (linux/fb.h).

You can find some exemples by searching "framebuffer draw pixels" in Google.

Answer (score 2):

To draw pixels on the screen would mean writing in your GPU Frame Buffer, a memory zone located into the card. 
To achieve this, you could use either CUDA (NVIDIA GPU only), OpenGL(Open-source).
That being said, the two of these are programming frameworks, and not the most easy to handle. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but be ready for some time overheard.

Answer (score 2):

to directly modify the screen you should use the GPU programming language (accessible from C by `#include`ing the right libraries)

The GPU programming language is extensive and a major hurtle to learn, But you can use it for what ever you need to do, including transferring data between the GPU and the CPU, programming algorithms, get the location, etc of the current window, setup multiple window images and shift between them during the 'blanking' retrace time, handle sprites, and much much more.

Answer (score 1):

there was an old file ["graphics.h"](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-graphics-programming-tutorial), which was on board with older versions of c++ (Borland c++ builder etc...), it was pretty low-level, as far as i remember

Now there is [Gdi+ in VS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d420az6e(v=vs.110).aspx), it also allows you to create simple graphics: lines pixels, etc... (it seems windows only, and not low-level)

so you can try both links, may be it will help